# Word cannot save document in WebDAV

Tags: ms-office, webdav

I am working on WebDAV implementation in our system. Now I am facing with the following problem.

When I am opening the document that placed in one of the subfolders, after editing it
I cannot save it. I am getting error: Word didn't saved document.

Despite this , the document that is placed in the root folder could be opened and edited.
I understand that the question is very specific , and I will get a lot of "thumb down" but I am fighting with it almost 3 days , and yet doesn't have any point to start.

Maybe one of you has also faced and struggled with the problem.

The Office Client is Office 2007 , the OS is Windows Wista / 7. 
Office 2010 doesn't have this problem. I can edit and save the document from any depth.

The trace of requests:
This is Trace when word is saving the document.

```
11/12/2011 11:52:52 : context type:PROPFIND
11/12/2011 11:52:52 : context type:PROPFIND
11/12/2011 11:52:52 : context type:LOCK
11/12/2011 11:52:52 : context type:GET
11/12/2011 11:52:53 : context type:HEAD
11/12/2011 11:53:02 : context type:PROPFIND
11/12/2011 11:53:03 : context type:HEAD
11/12/2011 11:53:03 : context type:PUT
11/12/2011 11:53:03 : context type:PROPPATCH
11/12/2011 11:53:03 : context type:HEAD
11/12/2011 11:53:08 : context type:UNLOCK
==============================================
This is the trace of requests when word is not saving the document.

11/12/2011 11:54:16 : context type:PROPFIND
11/12/2011 11:54:17 : context type:PROPFIND
11/12/2011 11:54:17 : context type:LOCK
11/12/2011 11:54:19 : context type:LOCK
11/12/2011 11:54:19 : context type:GET
11/12/2011 11:54:19 : context type:HEAD
11/12/2011 11:54:24 : context type:PROPFIND
11/12/2011 11:54:25 : context type:PROPFIND
11/12/2011 11:54:25 : context type:LOCK
```

The Lock request is sent couple times for a some reason. Anyone have an idea why this can happens ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you attached HTTP traces for both cases.

Comment: Julian Hi , I've added the traces , I can see that at the beginning , when word opening the file from subfolder , when sending the first lock , instead of sending GET , it sends another LOCK. Do you know what can be the reason ?

Comment: Probably because the response to the first LOCK wasn't as expected. You'll need to look at the header fields, the status codes, and the payload as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok , I've found the answer. Maybe this will be helpful for someone.

The problem was in Lock request. Since our system working with RTL characters set (Hebrew/Arabic) , the exact problem was in Url Decoding , the actual Physical path to file was corrupted and required some fix, so the lock request seems to be accomplished well but according to our implementation despite this , lock returned OK.

Regards,
Antony Hopkins